# Binding a custom collection of an entity to crystal report

Tags: c#, asp.net, collections, crystal-reports

```
public class Leads
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Npi { get; set; }
        public string LegalBusinessName { get; set; }
        public List<Calls> Calls { get; set; }


}
```

I am trying to bind List<Leads> to crystal report. The crystal report shows me data when I comment the Calls property (which is a collection of another entity called "Calls"). Is it even possible in crystal reports to bind a collection of an entity having another collection property.

Comment: if below answer is correct then mark it please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create sub-report for another collection. and add this sub-report to your main report.

Comment: Your answer did help me but I am also wondering if this is the only way where we can bind a collection of entity (having a collection property) to crystal report because if I add sub report then I am not utilizing the existing "Calls" property in the Leads entity.